# setting strings in gdb

Tags: c++, variables, string, gdb, setting

c++:

```
int main() 
    { 
    string a = "a"; 
    ... ... 
    }
```

when i debug in gdb:

> (gdb) set var a = "ok"
>   Invalid cast

I run the program and pause at a break point after string a has been initialized. I'm trying to set its value, but it complains about invalid cast. What's the proper syntax for this?

Comment: "setting" a string is a complex operation not necessarily supported by gdb.

Comment: ok... 
so you can set int variables using gdb, but not strings? I'm confused because setting strings doesn't seem much more complex than setting ints, and i know that this works: 

int main()
{
int b = 9;
}

(gdb) set var b = 8
// doesn't complain

"setting" is the correct term for what i'm trying to do, right?

Comment: "setting strings doesn't seem much more complex than setting ints" - well, it is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this:

```
call a.assign("ok")
```

This way, gdb knows right away that it needs to call a function (rather than what you tried using `operator=`), it knows what function to call (`std::string::assign`), and it doesn't need to convert types at all (since there's an overload of `assign` which matches exactly).